# Is it possible to determine the end behavior of a power series based on the sequence of coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, power-series, frobenius-method

**Question:** Given some sequence of coefficients (either explicitly or by way of a recursion formula) for a power series, is it possible to determine the end behavior (i.e. convergence, bounded, unbounded, etc.) of the that power series?

The [Maclaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for both $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ have an infinite [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence), but the latter converges to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ while the former diverges in the same limit. Likewise, the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$ and for $e^{-x^2}$ are very similar (e.g. both are even and alternating, and both divide by factorials), but while they both stay bounded, $\cos(x)$ does not converge as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$ whereas $e^{-x^2}$ does.

It would appear that alternating is a necessary condition for convergence to $0$ (I certainly haven't found any counter-examples), but it is clearly not a sufficient condition.

I'm particularly interested in this question as it applies to [series solution of differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite possible to see the asymptotic at $+\infty$ of an entire function just by looking at the asymptotic of its coefficients. If $f(x)\to 0$ then $f(x)+\epsilon x^n$ grows like a polynomial whereas the coefficients of both are quite similar.

Comment: This is a good point, but it doesn't actually seem to preclude determining asymptotic behavior since one could potentially separate the series into two or more parts through some sort of analysis which might identify the series as a convergent one with an additional polynomial piece. That is to say, if there is some obvious hiccup in the explicit formula for the sequence, then one could separate it out and the problem now becomes just about $f(x)$.

Comment: It means the power series is quite the worse representation to find the asymptotic, if your function satisfies a differential equation (involving elementary functions) then there are good chances we'll deduce its asymptotic, not from its power series but from the differential equation